# Problem when moving live shop to localhost

Tags: magento-1.5.1, localhost

I have a big problem to get my live shop working on a localhost.

I have changed all the files and have the following problem.

Each time I want to enter the local shop I´m redirected to the live shop.

If I disable my internet connection I will not be able to access my local site.

Hope someone can help me with this.

The live store I want to run on localhost is Version 1.5
I use Xampp.
Have changed local.xml and core_config_data in SQL.

Comment: Guess you did not change your base_url in the core_config_data table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your URL in core_config_date and then you need to go to /var/cache/ and clear the folder, then just to double check clear your browser data too!

Comment: Have the exact same URL in core_config_data as my localhost and have not found the problem witch is making me insane after spending a lot of time searching for an solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard practice to have the same URL for your local site as well but ofcourse you would need to set up a virtual host and have a host file entry in your local to be able to do that. By doing this you wouldn't need to make any changes to any core config data values.